# Merge data with timestamp without overriding old data

Tags: python, pandas

I have data `A` that looks like this:

```
timestamp,some_value
389434893,abc
348973493,dac
128197291,fgd
```

I have other data `B` that is the newer version of `A` (with more data):

```
timestamp,some_value
389434893,wwwwwwe # timestamp DID NOT CHANGE
348973493,wwwwags # timestamp DID NOT CHANGE
128197291,wwaswww # timestamp DID NOT CHANGE
982379283,ggg
```

This data exists in the form of `pandas.DataFrame`.

I want to merge `A` with `B` without affecting old rows from `A`, even if `some_value` has been changed. Result `R` should look like this:

```
timestamp,some_value
389434893,abc # copied from A
348973493,dac # copied from A
128197291,fgd # copied from A
982379283,ggg # new row from B
```

Order is guaranteed.

What pandas methods should I use to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
df_a = pd.concat([df_a,df_b[~df_b.timestamp.isin(df_a.timestamp)]])
```